# Retrieving data from specific node/child in firebase with getter,setter and adapter see more for details

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to display a custom listview with the data from my firebase. I have this existing code below and. I'm not getting any error when building it. But the app stops running. I think the error is from the datasnapshot. I wonder what did i do wrong. I'm new to android development. Thanks in advance

[image: This is what i'm trying to achieve]

[image: This is my firebase db structure]

I have this code in MainActivity

```
   mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Person");
        mRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                showData(dataSnapshot);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

}

private void showData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
    String sName, sSport, sTown;
    for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

 //   PeopleGetSet arr = new PeopleGetSet("name", "sport", "town");

        sName =   (ds.child("name").getValue(PeopleGetSet.class).getName());
        sSport =  (ds.child("sport").getValue(PeopleGetSet.class).getSport());
        sTown =   (ds.child("town").getValue(PeopleGetSet.class).getTown());

       /* Log.d(TAG, "Show Data name: " + info.getName());
        Log.d(TAG, "Show Data sport: " + info.getSport());
        Log.d(TAG, "Show Data town: " + info.getTown());*/

      PeopleGetSet info = new PeopleGetSet(sName, sSport, sTown);

        ArrayList<PeopleGetSet> array = new ArrayList<>();

        array.add(info);


        ViewDatabase adapter = new ViewDatabase(this, R.layout.adapter_view_layout, array);
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

And this is my code for my Adapter

```
public class ViewDatabase extends ArrayAdapter<PeopleGetSet> {
    private static final String TAG="ViewDatabase";
    private Context mContext;
    int mResource;

    public ViewDatabase(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull List<PeopleGetSet> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.mContext=context;
        mResource = resource;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        String name =getItem(position).getName();
        String sport =getItem(position).getSport();
        String town =getItem(position).getTown();

        PeopleGetSet person = new PeopleGetSet(name,sport, town);

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        convertView=inflater.inflate(mResource, parent, false);

        TextView tvName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        TextView tvSport = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        TextView tvTown = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        tvName.setText(name);
        tvSport.setText(sport);
        tvTown.setText(town);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

This is the error message

```
08-17 16:29:22.764 4943-4943/org.pelco3.www.customlistadapter E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: org.pelco3.www.customlistadapter, PID: 4943
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type org.pelco3.www.customlistadapter.PeopleGetSet
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzb(Unknown Source:259)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zza(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source:10)
    at org.pelco3.www.customlistadapter.MainActivity.showData(MainActivity.java:76)
    at org.pelco3.www.customlistadapter.MainActivity.access$100(MainActivity.java:22)
    at org.pelco3.www.customlistadapter.MainActivity$2.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:57)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzfc.zza(Unknown Source:13)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzgx.zzdr(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzhd.run(Unknown Source:71)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Comment: it will be good if you share error message or crash stacktrace for better understanding

Comment: It doesn't show error. The app just stops running.

Comment: you should be able to find error message in Logcat if your app stops running

Comment: Wait lemme try. Thanks for that

Comment: I added the error. It seems that it can't convert the value to string

Comment: yes you are doing it wrong.....have a look at your Snapshot its in array form  just use user model class to map this object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you were parsing object as a string that is why your app is crashing..
all you have to do is pass that snapshot in for each loop  to model class and add it your array list.

Cheers :)

```
ArrayList<PeopleGetSet> array = new ArrayList<>();
 private void showData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
        String sName, sSport, sTown;
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

      PeopleGetSet arr = ds.setvalue(PeopleGetSet.class);
    //Object obj= ds.setvalue(Object.class);


            array.add(info);



        }

   ViewDatabase adapter = new ViewDatabase(this, R.layout.adapter_view_layout, array);
            mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot. Another question can i still add a another listview in my custom listview? For ex. i will add list of hobbies?